# How to fix an `invalid BigNumber value` in ethers contract interaction?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, ethers.js

This is a Nft raffle dapp, which basically allows users to raffle erc720 tokens. I'm trying to implement this function using react.

Contract:
[buyTicket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE66j.png)

```
Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT    version=bignumber/5.7.0)
at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1)
at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1)
at Logger.throwArgumentError (index.ts:285:1)
at BigNumber.from (bignumber.ts:289:1)
at NumberCoder.encode (number.ts:25:1)
at array.ts:71:1
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at pack (array.ts:54:1)
at TupleCoder.encode (tuple.ts:54:1)
at AbiCoder.encode (abi-coder.ts:111:1)
```

But stuck up with an error, and doesn't even know why.

Here's the buyTicket handle:
[testing-Component-with-basic-logic-implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teStL.png)

Note: The unit being handled in the contract is in 'wei'.

Console output:
[console-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Dgd.png)

P.S: The contract is tested using remix and every function works fine (including the buyTicket function).

Comment: The value `undefined` cannot be converted to a BigNumber value.

Comment: Hello, please don't post code as pictures, people can't copy that, it also doesn't appear in search engine results.

Comment: It looks like you are passing a BigNumber to the `value` field when building the transaction. Convert the BigNumber to a number first

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.